# How to increase distance between time bins on Z axis?

Tags: arcgis-pro, global-scene

I have 19 time bins from 1993-2013 on vertical axis. I want to place them further away from each other along Z axis. Currently they're stacked on to each other like it looks now in the image attached.

Is there any way to increase the inter-bin distance at vertical scale?

[image]

Comment: When you have the chance, post the answers, but avoid posting comments in the answer box. Tks